# Writing program to choose values from a list of integers

Tags: python, list, integer, maximize

I have a list of integers, representing the yearly profit (in kilo euro) of n businesses (shops) along the high street in the City centre. I am given 4 (four) businesses ("for free"), that neighbour one another. The problem is to calculate which 4 I should take to maximize my yearly profit.
Given these numbers, write a PYTHON program to calculate which 4 I should take. As examples:
If the profits were 52, 67, -8, 43, -20 I should take the first 4 businesses.
If the profits were -20, 36, -10, -30, 3, 21 I would take no business (this is also allowed)

I'm not great at programming so any help would be appreciated, Cheers!

Initial attempt:

```
mylist=[52,67,-8,-43,-20]
>>> m=0
>>> for i in range(len(mylist)):
if m<mylist[i]:
    m=mylist[i]
```

I'm not sure about the last line though so I tried this too which wont work?:
    if mylist[i]>m:
        print mylist[i]

Comment: Please post your initial attempt

Comment: while asking questions about homework is not completely frowned on, doing your homework for you is. if you want to take a stab at it and then post it here for questions, you will get lots of help though.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a homework question that shows no prior effort.

Comment: this type of problem is good for a beginner to solve. Even if you don't know much, you can still do the very easy brute force solution, which would be checking every sequential set of four while remembering the biggest one.

Comment: all your attempt does is find the biggest element in the list. It might be helpful for you to start by describing your solution in english - it doesn't look like programming is the issue here, you just don't know how to logically find a solution.

Comment: So you're saying that I should break it down into steps in English and then translate it to code?

Comment: yes that is a good way to start, coding before you have a design is a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Separate your list of profits into adjacent groups of 4

   ```
   groups = zip(mylist,mylist[1:],mylist[2:],mylist[3:]) #there are many ways of doing this i picked this way
   ```
2. Pick the group with the largest sum

   ```
   print "I want :",max_sum(groups) #i will leave the implementation of this up to you
   ```